# Need help with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm new to ubuntu or linux at all. I'm trying to install the drivers for my GTX 550 Ti from nvidia's official website. I'm downloading the drivers for linux 64 bit (What i'm using). I'm choosing geforge and 500 series. After download I start the run file and then gedit starts. After that program takes a while on downloading stuff it stops working or says some numbers is not valid. and something about editing texts.  The point is I don't know how or why i cannot install the drivers so please help!

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: go to system settings --> additional drivers and then choose wich one you want.

Comment: You really should be installing the drivers through the supported methods - software center or the link above. If necessary use the xorg edgers ppa, but, take care as those packages can break your system.